# Left invariant metric in Carnot Groups

Tags: metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry, lie-groups

I've been studying lately Sub-Riemannian Geometry from the notes of Enrico LeDonne and I am stuck with something. In particular, I am studying Carnot groups seen as Carnot-Carathéodory Spaces endowed with the $d_{CC}$ metric ($d_{CC}(p,q)$ is the infimum of length among all horizontal/admissible curves that start at p and end at q).

At some part of the text, it is mentioned that the Carnot group $(G, D, || \cdot ||)$ with $\mathfrak{g} = V_1 \bigoplus ... \bigoplus V_s$ stratifiable endowed with the distribution defined by $D_q = (L_q)_* V_1$ and $||v|| = ||(L_q)^* v||$ for all $q \in G$ and $v \in D_q$ makes true that $d_{CC}$ is left-invariant. I could prove it using the definition of left-invariance of the metric. However, the author mentions that by left-invariance of the metric it is true that $d_{CC}(e,p) < \infty$ for all $p \in G \rightarrow d_{CC}(p,q) < \infty$ for all $p,q \in G$. I've tried to prove that affirmation and I get why it must be true, but I haven't been able to get a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Finiteness of $d_{CC}$ follows from Lemma 1.40 in Folland, Stein "Hardy spaces on homogeneous groups". (I know this result from this book, however you can find it in other books)

**Lemma 1.40** says that if $G$ is a Carnot group then exists $N \in \mathbb N$ and $\delta>0$ (which depends only on $G$) such that for any $x \in G$ exist $x_1, \dots, x_N \in \exp(V_1)$ and $|x_i| \le \delta |x|$ where $|\cdot|$ is a homogeneous norm (equivalent to $d_{CC}$).

You can define
$$
d_{CC}(x, y) = \inf\bigg\{\int\limits_a^b \|\dot\gamma(t)\|\,dt \mid \gamma\colon [a,b] \to G, \text{$\gamma$ is horizontal path with end points $x$ and $y$}  \bigg\}.  
$$
We say that $\gamma$ piecewise smooth path is *horizontal* if $\dot\gamma(t) \in V_1(\gamma(t))$ for almost every $t$.

From lemma 1.40 one can find a path with finite length that's why $d_{CC}(e,x) < \infty$ for all $x\in G$.
And $d_{CC}(x,y) = d_{CC}(e, x^{-1}y) < \infty$ for all $x,y\in G$.